# Cloud firestore not ordering problems when query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

My query it's not ordering. Actually it doesn't response. I receive an empty results screen when trying with this:

```
let stateQuery = firestore.collection('categories').where('user', '==', uid).orderBy('name'); 

        stateQuery.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const docs = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
            docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
          });
          setCategories(docs);
        });
      };
```

I tried also to do this, and nothing:

```
 let stateQuery = firestore.collection('categories').where('user', '==', uid);
 let stateQuery2 =  stateQuery.orderBy('name');
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this query to do, other than what you observe?  Please edit the question to be clear, showing specific examples of documents you expect to see in the results.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your request. If I do not use orderBy, the query brings all the collections and that's ok. I want the same result but ordered by the field "name". When I use orderBy the result comes empty.

Comment: Is your field 'name' a number in your database?

Comment: Can you confirm that the `categories` documents have a field `name`, with a value? (Cf. the doc => "An `orderBy()` clause also filters for existence of the given fields. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given fields.")

Comment: Yes, there is a field "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your query requires a Composite index. Documentation on composite indexes is on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview).

Check the console for an error message which should include the link necessary to create the composite index. When I run a similar query on my database, I get this link

https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/(PROJECTNAME)/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Xd1.....XTY